# Why can't I access the file react.js from the react-0.12.2 webjar?

Tags: playframework, reactjs, playframework-2.3, webjars

I use the webjar react-0.12.2 in my Play Framework 2.3 project, and I've depended on it like so:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "react" % "0.12.2"
)
```

If I try to access 'react.js' though, like in the following example, I get an error due to there being multiple matches for react.js:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("react.js"))'>
```

The error:

```
MultipleMatchesException: Multiple matches found for react.js. Please provide a more specific path, for example by including a version number.
```

I've found that accessing 'react.min.js' instead works, so there's a problem with the 'react.js' path. But why is it going wrong, is there a bug?

Comment: Answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28350272/77409

Comment: @JamesWard Would you mind writing a detailed answer explaining why the main "react.js" can't be located and how to rectify this?

Comment: I just released `webjars-play` version `2.3.0-3` which adds a helper to make dealing with this easier.  Details below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are in fact two instances of `react.js` in the WebJar. So if you want to use the locator you need to be more specific about the path.  Before `webjars-play` version `2.3.0-3` there isn't an single method call way to do this so you can do one of the following:

Use Play 2.3's asset pipeline and access the file via the extract dir:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("lib/react/react.js")'>
```

Or you can create a helper method like:

```
def fullPath(webjar: String, path: String): String = {
  val version = webJarAssetLocator.getWebJars.get(webjar)
  s"$webjar/$version/$path"
}
```

Which would be used like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(fullPath("react", "react.js"))'>
```

Or if you upgrade to `webjars-play` version `2.3.0-3` then you can use the now built-in `WebJarAssets.fullPath` method:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.fullPath("react", "react.js"))'>
```